# Can electron jumps to higher energy state without absorbing photon?

Tags: energy, electrons, photoelectric-effect

The shorter the wavelength of the electromagnetic wave the more energy it carries, when it hits an atom and gets absorbed the electron gains kinetic energy and jumps to higher energy state. Are there any alternate mechanism whereby an electron can perform a jump into different energy state without exchanging photon?

Comment: How about neutrino scattering with exchange of a virtual W or Z? I don't know if the cross-sections are large enough to observe this as an atomic transition.

Comment: @CuriousOne one might argue neutrino and electron are very similar.

Comment: Are they? I don't think the folks who are building neutrino detectors will agree with that. An electron detector costs cents and can be the size of a grain of sand, a neutrino detector... not so much. Maybe it would be better if you told us what you are really looking for? :-)

Comment: Incident electrons and ions can result in excited states. They are the basis for analytical composition measurements.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I'm wondering if an electron can become excited without absorbing photon?

Comment: I am wondering if you understood my comment. :-)

Comment: @JohnCuster: All electromagnetic scattering processes are mediated by photons.

Comment: @JonCuster: do you mean collision between an electron and other particle?

Comment: @CuriousOne - indeed. That was more a prod to the poster to better define the question. They appear to have something specific in mind.

Comment: @JonCuster: Not sure the OP isn't just naive about the physics of these interactions. He/she certainly didn't spend a single second on neutrino detection.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I think you are saying in a neutral current interaction the neutrino can deposit some energy and momentum to accelerate the electron, did I get it this time round?

Comment: What I am saying is that you could have found this out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The shorter the wavelength of the electromagnetic wave the more energy it carries, when it hits an atom and gets absorbed the electron gains kinetic energy and jumps to higher energy state.

This happens only if the energy of the photon is equal (within the width of the energy levels) to the difference between the energy levels. The "gaining kinetic energy and jumping" is only within the crude Bohr model . In the quantum mechanical exact formulation the electrons change [orbitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbitals).

> My question is are there any alternate mechanism whereby an electron can perform a jump into different energy state without exchanging photon?

The electron is an elementary particle and is trapped in the energy levels of an atom by electromagnetic interactions. These have been studied extensively and there exists a theory that can calculate the probabilities of interaction for specific problems, which depends on [Feynman diagrams.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) In this there exist virtual particles and particularly virtual photons which can be exchanged in  atoms interacting with atoms.

Therefore a probability can be calculated for an atom scattering off an atom to raise the energy level of an electron to a higher one, by the kinetic energy transferred represented as a virtual photon exchange. This probability is finite and this is another way that the electrons can get to a higher energy level. This is true for molecules scattering on molecules and all similar cases. (Actually this is the way black body radiation is created)

More exotic exchanges could theoretically exist,but they would still go through virtual particle exchange diagrams and  the probabilities are very very small for other interactions than the electromagnetic one due to the values of the coupling constants and the very small energies involved in atomic (etc) energy levels.

If one considers virtual photons, which have the quantum numbers of the photon but are off mass shell as equivalent to real on mass shell photons the answer is , no always a photon is involved, real or virtual.

Comment: for the non-particle-physics person, can you clarify for me if electron-neutron scattering is also described through virtual photon interactions? It would seem the most likely option but I defer to your knowledge.

Comment: The electron interacts at first order, i.e. with simple one vertex diagrams with the electromagnetic and the weak interaction. The neutron, with the strong, electromagnetic and weak interaction through its constituent quarks. Thus low energy electron neutron scattering will go with exchange of virtual photons, because at  low momenta if the interaction the probability of diagrams with an exchange of virtual W's and Z's is very very small. For high energies, the virtual exchanges of  Z's and W's start being of measurable probability